# keep getting invalid host header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, fetch, render

I have a multiplayers react socket io game .
it works fine locally
but when i try to deploy it on render - the server part works fine,
but in the client i see the components log , but on page load
i keep getting "Invalid host header" error .
I have tried:
Button a the servers url as prefix to fetch path
adding a proxy line to package.json that contains the render server url
adding the variables to render settings:
disableHostCheck true
allowedHosta: true
in the render variables sections.

Nothin helps ! I keep getting "Invalid host header" where i run the client on render .
Any help will be much appreciated.

// App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import NameForm from "./components/NameForm";
import RoomsList from "./components/RoomsList";
import Game from "./components/Game";
import { initRoomsFunc } from "./helpers/init"; // Import the initialization function

const AppContainer = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: snow;
`;

// const Title = styled.h1`
//   margin-top: 15px;
//   font-size: 4rem;
// `;
console.log("12-12-12-12")

function App() {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");
  const [roomsInitialData, setRoomsInitialData] = useState(null); // State to hold initialization data
  const [dataIsSet, setDataIsSet] = useState(false); // State to hold initialization data

  useEffect(() => {
    // Initialize the app when it mounts
    const init = async () => {
      console.log("6666")

      try {
        const initRoomsObj = await initRoomsFunc();
        setRoomsInitialData(initRoomsObj);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error initializing the app:", error);
      }
    };
    init();
  }, []);

  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("5555")

    if  ( roomsInitialData )  {
      setDataIsSet(true)
    }
  }, [roomsInitialData]);

  return (
    <Router>
      <AppContainer>
        <Routes>
{ dataIsSet? <Route path="/rooms" element={<RoomsList userName={userName} roomsInitialData={roomsInitialData} />} /> : null}
          <Route path="/name" element={<NameForm setUserName={setUserName} />} />
          {/* Add the route for the game page with :roomId parameter */}
          <Route path="/game/:roomId" element={<Game />} />

          <Route path="" element={<NameForm setUserName={setUserName} />} />
        </Routes>
      </AppContainer>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useNavigate  } from "react-router-dom";

import {  updateCurentRoomAndActiveRooms,
  removeUpdatedRoomDataListener,
  emitAddMemberToRoom
} from "../clientSocketServices";

const GameContainer = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: snow;

`;

const RoomsList = ({ userName, roomsInitialData }) => {
  
  const [currentRoom, setCurrentRoom] = useState({});
  const [updatedActiveRooms, setUpdatedActiveRooms] = useState([]);
  const navigate = useNavigate(); // Get the navigate function from React Router


  const handleJoinRoom = async (chosenRoom) => {
      console.log("1111")
      emitAddMemberToRoom({
        playerName: userName,
        chosenRoom: chosenRoom,
      });  
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("2222")

    // Listen for updated room data from the server - 
    // when arive - set updated curentRoom and activeRooms values sent by server
    updateCurentRoomAndActiveRooms(setUpdatedActiveRooms, setCurrentRoom);
    // Clean up the event listener when the component unmounts
    return () => {
      removeUpdatedRoomDataListener();
    };
  }, []); // Empty dependency array ensures the effect runs only once when the component mounts


  // Use useEffect to listen for changes in updatedActiveRooms and currentRoom
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("3333")

    // Check if updatedActiveRooms has a length greater than 0
    if (currentRoom != undefined && currentRoom.id >= 0) {
      console.log("IN RoomsList 2222 -- useEffect[updatedActiveRooms, currentRoom] -- passing to GAME -- currentRoom: ", currentRoom);
      // // Navigate to the game page
      // navigate(`/game/${currentRoom.id}`, {
      //   state: { userName, currentRoom },
      // });
    }
  }, [currentRoom]);
  
  console.log("4444")


  return (
    <GameContainer>
      <h3>Available Rooms:</h3>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Room Name</th>
            <th>Difficulty</th>
            <th>Max Members</th>
            <th>Info</th>
            <th>Join</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {roomsInitialData.map((room) => (
            <tr key={room.id}>
              <td>{room.name}</td>
              <td>{room.difficulty}</td>
              <td>{room.maxMembers}</td>
              <td>
                <a
                  href={room.info}
                  target="_blank"
                  rel="noopener noreferrer"
                >
                  {room.name}
                </a>
              </td>
              <td>
                <button onClick={() => handleJoinRoom(room)}>Join</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </GameContainer>
  );
};

export default RoomsList;
let activeRooms = [];

console.log("IN serverSocketServices.js");

const serverSocketServices = (io) => {

  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    
    socket.on("CREATE_ROOM_AND_ADD_PLAYER", ({ playerName, chosenRoom }) => {
      console.log("IN serverSocketServices - ON-CREATE_ROOM_AND_ADD_PLAYER  -- chosenRoom: ", chosenRoom);
      let existingRoom, newRoom, updatedRoom;
      let existingPlayer = {}, newPlayer = {};

      existingRoom = activeRooms.find((oneOfTheRooms) => oneOfTheRooms.id === chosenRoom.id);

      if (!existingRoom) {  // HANDLE NEW ROOM
        newRoom = {
          ...chosenRoom,
          currentPlayers: [],
        };

        console.log("SERVER CREATING NEW ROOM -- newRoom.id: ", newRoom.id);
        updatedRoom = newRoom;
      } else {  // ROOM EXISTS
        console.log("ROOM ", existingRoom.id, "already exists");
        updatedRoom = existingRoom;
      }

      // HANDLE PLAYER
      // Check if the player with the same name already exists
      existingPlayer = updatedRoom.currentPlayers && updatedRoom.currentPlayers.find((player) => player.name === playerName);

      if (existingPlayer) {
        console.log("Player", playerName, "already exists in room", updatedRoom.id);
      } else {
        // HANDLE NEW PLAYER
        console.log("Adding player", playerName, "to chosenRoom:", updatedRoom.id);
        newPlayer = {  // CREATE SOCKET-ID FOR NEW PLAYER
          socketId: socket.id,
          name: playerName,
          email: "",
          isWinner: false,
          isActive: true,
        };
        updatedRoom.currentPlayers.push(newPlayer);
      }

      // Find the index of the existing room in activeRooms
      const existingRoomIndex = activeRooms.findIndex((room) => room.id === updatedRoom.id);

      if (existingRoomIndex !== -1) {  // If it exists, update that room in activeRooms
        activeRooms[existingRoomIndex] = updatedRoom;
      } else {
        // If it doesn't exist, add the updatedRoom to activeRooms
        activeRooms.push(updatedRoom);
      }
      console.log("Emitting from server activeRooms:", activeRooms);
      console.log("Emitting from server updatedRoom:", updatedRoom);

      // Join the socket to the room
      socket.join(updatedRoom.id);

      // Emit to all players in the room
      io.emit("UPDATED_ROOMS_AND_ROOM_DATA", activeRooms, updatedRoom);
    });

        
    socket.on("CURENT_ROOM_CHANGED", ( updatedRoom ) => {
        
      console.log("IN serverSocketServices - ON-UPDATE_ROOMS_AND_ROOM  -- updatedRoom: ", updatedRoom);

      // Find the index of the existing room in activeRooms
      const existingRoomIndex = activeRooms.findIndex((room) => room.id === updatedRoom.id);

      if (existingRoomIndex !== -1) {  // If it exists, update that room in activeRooms
        activeRooms[existingRoomIndex] = updatedRoom;
      } 
      console.log("Emitting from server activeRooms:", activeRooms);
      console.log("Emitting from server updatedRoom:", updatedRoom);

      // Emit to all players in the room
      io.emit("UPDATED_ROOMS_AND_ROOM_DATA", activeRooms, updatedRoom);
    });

    socket.on("MATCHED_CARDS_CHANGED", ( matchedCards ) => {
      // Emit to all players in the room
      io.emit("UPDATED_MATCHED_CARDS", matchedCards);
    });

  });

};

module.exports = serverSocketServices;
"use strict";
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const socket = require("socket.io");
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();
const server = http.Server(app);

// Add the 'cors' middleware with options to allow requests from 'http://localhost:8080'
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "*",
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// Add the following lines to handle Socket.IO connections
const io = socket(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  //   allowedHeaders: ["secretHeader"],  // IN RENDER var disableHostCheck: true
  //   credentials: true,
  // },
} });

// Serve static files from the "public" directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));


  app.get("/database/Cards.json", (req, res) => {
  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "database", "Cards.json");
  res.sendFile(filePath);
});

app.get("/database/rooms.json", (req, res) => {
  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "database", "rooms.json");
  res.sendFile(filePath);
});

const serverSocketServices = require("./serverSocketServices");// Use the io instance to invoke serverSocketServices
serverSocketServices(io);

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
server.listen(PORT, console.log(`Listening to ${PORT}!`));
import io from "socket.io-client";

// const PROXY_URL = 'http://localhost:5000'; // local server port
const RENDER_PROXY_URL = 'https://spotty-join-production.up.railway.app/'; // RENDER server port

export const socket = io(RENDER_PROXY_URL);

console.log("IN clientSocketServices -- socket: ", socket)

// Broadcast player actions to all playerS in the room

export const emitAddMemberToRoom = ({ playerName, chosenRoom }) => {
  socket.emit('CREATE_ROOM_AND_ADD_PLAYER', { playerName, chosenRoom });
};

// Function to broadcast the current room data
export const emitCurentRoomChanged = (curentRoom) => {
  // Emit the updated room data to the server
  socket.emit("CURENT_ROOM_CHANGED", curentRoom);
};

// Function to broadcast the current room data
export const emitCurentMatchedCards = (matchedCards) => {
  // Emit the updated room data to the server
  socket.emit("MATCHED_CARDS_CHANGED", matchedCards);
};

// Function to listen for updated room data from the server
export const updateCurentRoomAndActiveRooms = (setUpdatedActiveRooms, setCurentRoom) => {
  socket.on("UPDATED_ROOMS_AND_ROOM_DATA", (serverUpdatedActiveRooms, serverUpdatedCurentRoom) => {
    // Update the state with the received data
    setCurentRoom(serverUpdatedCurentRoom);
    setUpdatedActiveRooms(serverUpdatedActiveRooms);
  });
};

// Function to listen for updated room data from the server
export const updateMatchedCards = (setMatchedCards) => {
  socket.on("UPDATED_MATCHED_CARDS", (matchedCards) => {
    // Update the state with the received data
    setMatchedCards(matchedCards);
  });
};

// Clean up the event listener when needed
export const removeUpdatedRoomDataListener = () => {
  socket.off("UPDATED_ROOMS_AND_ROOM_DATA");
};

// Clean up the event listener when needed
export const removeUpdatedMatchedCards = () => {
  socket.off("UPDATED_MATCHED_CARDS");
};
```